# Displaying images and text on GUI whithout pushbutton

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How to display a string in  edit box in matlab GUI. The gui has no pushbutton. Hence when it is run the string should directly be displayed on the gui text box.  Similarly for images.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

either manually write in the string by opening the property inspector (double click on edit box) and scroll down to 'string' and write your string or just call the handle and set it in a callback, i.e. set(handles.edit1,'String','This is my string')

Comment: For clarification, set(handles.edit1,'String','This is my string') must be included in the initialization code.